# Opening Syslinux to make a USB bootable?

Tags: usb-drive, bootloader

I don't understand how to open and use Syslinux so that it can create a bootable USB. I am not familiar with a lot of the language on the standard answers, so less tech is better. I downloaded version 3.11 and opened and extracted it with Bitzipper: that works. The procedure I am trying to follow says this:

"Download Syslinux-this is a utility that will make the FAT32 partition of your USB stick bootable. With the Windows Command Prompt, cd over to the "win32" subdirectory of the Syslinux directory you downloaded and type the following, where "F:" is the drive letter for the TYPE11 partition on your USB stick:

syslinux -ma F:"

I can't find a win32 subdirectory, and I can't get the syslinux.exe file to run. Is there a different version of syslinux I need to find? 
thanks,
DM

Answer (score 2):

Do you specifically need to make a USB stick bootable, or are you trying to create a bootable Ubuntu Live USB?

If all you want is a bootable Ubuntu USB, you may find unetbootin friendlier, and it takes care of making the stick bootable for you:

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

If you need to make the USB stick bootable for another purpose and really need syslinux, it looks like the instructions you followed are for newer versions, since 3.11 looks to be quite a bit outdated. You may want to download Syslinux 4.04 from here:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/

when you unzip it you'll indeed see the win32 directory your instructions point to, with a syslinux.exe binary.

Give it a try and let me know if either of these solutions work for you.

Comment: What happens with the syslinux 4.04 is that I extract it with bitzipper, open the win32 folder, and try to run the syslinux program inside that. The ms-dos 'command' screen blinks and then disappears. Same happened when I tried this on a machine running obuntu (as when I tried it on this machine running windows). I am obviously ignorant of something here.

Comment: Open a command prompt and change to the win32 directory, and type "syslinux -ma F:". Maybe then you'll get a useful error message. Syslinux is meant to be used from the command prompt, double-clicking on it is not going to be useful. If you do prefer a GUI program as opposed to a command-line utility, I strongly suggest you use unetbootin as it may be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is wrong.  You are mistyping the 'switches' '-m' and '-a'.  What you are mistakenly typing is ma when you need this (in full) instead:

syslinux.exe -m -a X:    (Where X: is your USB drive).

This will definitely solve your problem buddy.  Keep hackin'.

Answer (score 0):

Still not working?

That's because when you 'cd' (Or, 'change directory') you are changing the directory to one of TWO 'WIN32' Directories.

My path is:  C:\syslinux6.03\bios\win64

Note the NEW 'bios' folder/directory.

P.S:  I have been hacking away at getting BlackArch Linux/GNU distro installed for the past hour and came across your struggle, and, knowing I could help, spent five mins typing these solutions.

Good luck, and keep hackin'!